# Ignore files with .db extension in folder location

Tags: java

I am facing issues when trying to ignore files with.db extension placed in folder location(say (\test\folder) using below java code.The code on execution is not working as expected and the files containing .db extension isn't ignored [which is what we are looking at in our requirement].

Please advice what changes or missing points are there in the below enlisted code.

I have pasted the code snippet causing trouble and not  ignoring the file of .db extension.

```
String mess1 = "";
String mess2 = "";
String ext = "Thumbs.db";

Boolean result = false;
try{
    File folder =  new File(folderPath);
    System.out.println(folder);
    if(folder.exists()){
    File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

    if(listOfFiles.length > 0){
        for(int i=0;i<listOfFiles.length;i++){
            String name= listOfFiles[i].toString();

            if(name.equalsIgnoreCase(ext)){
                out.println(name);   
                result = false;  
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to ignore *all* files with an `.db` extension, not just `Thumbs.db`, you'd better use `name.endsWith(".db")`.  And then it does not matter if you use `File.toString()` or `File.getName()`. Alternatively you could implement a `java.io.FileFilter`.

Answer (score 0):

`File.toString()` does not do what you probably expect it to do. It returns the pathname string of this abstract pathname, not the name of the file.

Try `File.getName()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `file.getName()` instead of `file.toString()` to abtain the name of the file and not the pathname.

Then you should use `name.matches()` instead of `name.equals()` to obtain all the files that have .db extension and not only the one with the name Thumbs.db

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code which will print files ending with .db extension.

```
String mess1 = "";
String mess2 = "";
String ext = ".db";

Boolean result = false;
try{
       File folder =  new File("C:/FTP/");
       System.out.println(folder);
       if(folder.exists()){
             File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

             if(listOfFiles.length > 0){
                    for(int i=0;i<listOfFiles.length;i++){
                           String name= listOfFiles[i].getName();

                           if(name.endsWith(ext))
                           {
                                  System.out.println(name);  
                                  result = false;  
                           }
                    }
             }
       }
}catch(Exception e) {}
```